# TargetInvocationException occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code when using DbGeometry

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I've been getting this error when trying to open up one of my web pages. The code behind throws a TargetInvocationException on the following code:

```
public DbGeometry DynamicGeo
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(WKT))
                return null;
            else
                return DbGeometry.FromText(WKT, 4326);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas as to wy or how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Been having sql issues with the code and thought my tinkering my have made something unstable. Mostly just trying to cover all my bases since I'm not 100% sure where the issue is originating.